# Javascript - getting the selected dropdown value return null

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting error TypeError: e is null when trying to retrieve the value of the selected item in a dropdown list through window.alert(idName);. Sorry if this is a obvious error as I am new to javascript.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function openContent(evt, displayInfo) {
        // Declare all variables
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        var numusrs = ["-50","-100", "-150"];
        var permission = [" Admin-", " Editor-"];

        var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
        var idName = displayInfo + numusrs[0] + permission[0] + e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

        window.alert(idName);

     }
</script></head>
<body>
  <select class="dropdown">
     <option value="Mean"> Mean </option>
     <option value="Max"> Max </option>
     <option value="50thPct"> 50th Percentil </option>
     <option value="75thPct"> 75th Percentil </option>
     <option value="95thPct"> 95th Percentil </option>
     <option value="99thPct"> 99th Percentil </option>
  </select>

 <ul class="tab">
     <li style="font-size:large;" >Summary</li>
     <ul class="subtab">
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'APISummary')">API</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'TestSummary')">TEST</a></li>
     </ul>
     <li style="font-size:large;">Detail</li>
     <ul class="subtab">
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Detail-API-150 Admin-Mean')">API</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Detail-TEST-150 Admin-Mean')">TEST</a></li>
     </ul>
  </ul>
```

Comment: typo with dropdown `attr` use `id="dropdown"`, check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<select>` has a `class` of `dropdown`:

```
<select class="dropdown">
```

But you're searching by `id`:

```
var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
```

The quickest fix is to add the ID to your `<select>` too:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
```

I say "quickest", because if you change `class="dropdown"` to `id="dropdown"` it may have an affect on styling that potentially isn't included in your question.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it. Will select as answer after 7 minutes. Yeah, it's a very obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you are getting the `dropdown` selected value by its `id` but in `HTML` you have given the `dropdown` class. so

1. Change `class="dropdown"` to `id="dropdown"`
2. Get `dropdown` value using this code

   ```
    var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   ```

Using `.text` will return the text inside `options`.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't done Javascript in a while so apologies if I'm wrong but you may mean to use getElementByClassName.